# Can someone help me with the method behind this shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

Can someone help me with the method behind this linux command? I know what the outputs are, just need to know how you figure them out.

```
#!/bin/sh
i=0
for a in 9 8 7 6 5 4
do
    j=1
    for b in 1 2 3 4
    do
        let "j+=2"
    done
    let "i+=1"
done
echo "i=$i j=$j"
```

Comment: Have you tried running the script?

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script. It will then show you each command as it executes, including all the variable substitutions.

Comment: Are you asking about the syntax or the algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Fist, indenting helps make it clearer:

```
#!/bin/sh                      

i=0                            
for a in 9 8 7 6 5 4           
    do                         
        j=1                    
        for b in 1 2 3 4       
            do                 
                let "j+=2"     
            done               
        let "i+=1"             
    done                       
echo "i=$i j=$j"
```

The a and b variables are never used, other than to make the outer loop execute 6 times (one loop for each number in the list 9 8 7 6 5 4) and to make the inner loop execute 4 times (one loop for each number in the list 1 2 3 4).

The outer loop adds 1 to the value of i (initialized to zero) each of the 6 times through the loop, ending up with a value of 6.

The inner loop adds 2 to the value of j each of the 4 times through the loop. Even though the inner loop itself is executed 6 times, since j is re-initialized to 1 before each execution of the inner loop, the final value of j is only 9 (1+2+2+2+2).